# How To Annotate an Argument That Can Be Cast As Boolean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm starting to get into type hints (aka annotations) in python 3.6, and I can't figure some of the dynamic aspects of this feature.

I wrote the following piece of code, and I want to add annotation and not sure how, even after looking through the docs on type hinting.

This is the function:

```
def validate_expression(expression: ?):
    try:
        assert expression
    except AssertionError as e:
        ...
```

`expression` needs to be anything that an assert works on (assuming any expression for which `bool(expression)` is valid).

What should I write instead of the question mark?

**UPDATE:**

I know that most python expressions can be cast as a Boolean, but the context in which I write this code is one where it is reasonable to expect an expression to *not* be a assertable.

The relevant example in my case is `pandas.DataFrame`. Running
`bool(pandas.DataFrame())` raises an error, and I have good reason to expect that someone might try to pass a dataframe to the validation function.

**UPDATE 2:**
Following [Chepner](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s comments and answer, I understand now that:
 1. In the vast majority of cases, any python expression will have a valid casting to Boolean, and this is either covered by `typing.Any` or by not adding annotation at all.
 2. In the edge case I was interested in, which is `bool(pandas.DataFrame()) # --> ValueError`, annotations won't help since this is a runtime error.
 3. If there is another edge case that is relevant for static type hinting, I am not aware of it.
 4. Given the rarity/non-existence of a relevant example, there's no out of the box type that generically describes just the quality of the ability to be casted to boolean (similar to `typing.Iterable`), and as far as I'm concerned it is not worth bending over backwards to address such an edge case (although it would be interesting to hear of relevant example and a bend-y solution!)

Comment: *Anything* can be treated in a boolean context; if nothing else, an `object` is considered `True` by default.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this? A type hint might not be the right tool for the job. Instead maybe just add `except ValueError` to the `try` block?

Comment: @tobias_k my assumption in asking this question is that there's just a hidden magic word that _just does that_, like `typing.Iterable`, but it seems like there's no such case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any value whatsoever can be used in a boolean context. An instance of `object` is considered to be a truthy value unless a descendent class provides an alternate definition; anything that is considered false (like an empty list, an empty str, an empty dict, `False` itself, etc) does so because it has been specially defined to be so.

As such, the only type hint you could use is `typing.Any`:

```
from typing import Any


def validate_expression(expression: Any):
    try:
        assert expression
    except AssertionError as e:
        ...
```

which, really, is barely worth stating explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Unfortunately, this is not always true, for example `pandas.DataFrame` doesn't have a boolean value.

And in my context (writing a very lightweight validation framework for data scientists using pandas), this is an important edge case I'd like to support.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll see if I can address that (though it won't be pretty).

Comment: Hm. The problem with `DataFrame` is that it doesn't really follow the rules; `DataFrame.__nonzero__` doesn't return a value at all; it raises an exception. In that sense, its beyond the scope of what *static* typing can capture, because its failure to have a truthiness value happens at *runtime*.

Comment: So If I get it right, the problem is that if I write `validate(pandas.DataFrame)` any annotation framework will get confused by this, even if I add an annotation to the input argument?

Comment: Not confused, but you can't (short of simulating the code line by line) determine at compile time if the code will raise a `ValueError` at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your update 2: here's a somewhat janky way of accomplishing what you want to do:

1. Create a custom [Protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) that matches any type that defines a `__bool__` method. (And perhaps also the `__nonzero__` method, if you also want to support Python 2.)
2. Find or create stubs for the pandas library. Ensure that the type hints for `DataFrame` do *not* contain the `__bool__` method. That is, will *not* match the protocol.
3. Create a function that uses your custom protocol as the type hint.

For example:

```
# If you're using Python 3.8+
from typing import Protocol

# If you're not, run 'pip install typing_extensions' and do the below instead
from typing_extensions import Protocol

class SupportsBool(Protocol):
    def __bool__(self) -> bool: ...

class MyFakeDataFrame:
    # ...snip...
    pass

class MyFakeBoolableThing:
    def __bool__(self) -> bool:
        return True

def validate_expression(x: SupportsBool) -> None:
    bool(x)

# These all type-check!

validate_expression(True)
validate_expression(0)
validate_expression(MyFakeBoolableThing())

# This will *not* typecheck

validate_expression(MyFakeDataFrame())

# Perhaps surprisingly, these will also not typecheck:

validate_expression("foobar")
validate_expression([1, 2, 3])
```

The reason why the latter two expressions will not type-check is because neither strings nor lists actually define a custom `__bool__` method (or `__nonzero__` method in Python 2): instead, they define a `__len__` method, and the `bool(...)` function will fall back to checking `__len__` if `__bool__`/`__nonzero__` doesn't exist.

If you do want your validate function to accept such expressions, you'd need to use a type like `Union[SupportsBool, SupportsInt]` -- but unfortunately, I believe the pandas DataFrame class *does* implement a functional `__len__` method, so you're back to square zero if you take that approach.

So basically, in this case you're either (1) forced into rejecting certain types like str or list that do meaningful things when bool'd, or (2) forced into accepting `pandas.DataFrame` as an acceptable boolable thing.

Comment: Very cool. As you say, I'm not sure it solves my specific problem with pandas.DataFrame, but it's good to know of the options I have using typing.Protocol (in python 3.8+ or with a backport). 

So thanks!